# Better way to expose functions in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, export

I have a directory where I am keeping all of my DAO files which contains methods to interact with MySQL server.

My DAO directory looks like this

```
| -- dao
  | -- user.dao.ts
  | -- employee.dao.ts
```

I have my controllers directory that looks like this

```
| -- controller
  | -- user.controller.ts
  | -- employee.controller.ts
```

Each DAO file contains functions which may have same names like:

```js
function insertOne() {}

function insertMany() {}
```

I am utilising these DAO functions in my controller file, I am importing multiple DAO files in one controller file as I want to use multiple DAO functions in one controller

I have two ways to export the functions from DAO files:

First Approach:

```js
export function insertOne() {}

export function insertMany() {}
```

Second Approach:

```js
function insertOne() {}

function insertMany() {}

export default {
  insertOne,
  insertMany
};
```

I know it is better to export individual functions, as we can import only the functions that we need in that file, but in my case, the function names would clash, so, what should be the best approach to deal with this ?

If I use first approach I would do something like this in my controller

```js
import * as userDAO from "../dao/user.dao.ts";
import * as empDAO from "../dao/emp.dao.ts";

// import { insertOne } from "../dao/user.dao.ts"; // can't do this as name would clash

userDAO.insertOne();
empDAO.insertOne();
```

If I use second approach I would do something like this in my controller

```js
import userDAO from "../dao/user.dao.ts";
import empDAO from "../dao/emp.dao.ts";

userDAO.insertOne();
empDAO.insertOne();
```

Am I doing anything wrong by keeping the same name methods in every DAO file? Looking for suggestions and similar approaches I can add to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong in second approach, i dont think you have thousands of files. So what is wrong if you will export a couple of functions which will not be used? People are importing lodash library, using 5 percents of it. I guess you pay too much attention to this.

But my suggestion is to create classes. Make one

```
class DAOModel {
  insertOne () {}
  insertMany () {}
}
```

and in your files create classes inheriting DAOModel and pass an instance of this class, may be making all methods static

or creating just objects

```
const personsDAO = {
  insertOne() {...},
  insertMany() {...},
}

export default personsDAO
```

then you will forget your headache

Comment: Yes, agree. Importing a file with 10-20 functions in multiple places is not something I should worry about. I agree the class one makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `as` syntax to rename named imports as well:

```
import {insertOne as userInsertOne} from "../dao/user.dao.ts";
import {insertOne as empInsertOne} from "../dao/emp.dao.ts";
//You can use shorter names if you want, of course...

userInsertOne();
empInsertOne();
```

Comment: Yeah I know this, but this will be too much of work

Comment: @AmirSaleem If you have a few functions to import in a file, use this, if you have a lot, then use the `* as something` approach. I cannot recommend better, as nothing can be perfect...